# What are cookie clicker's secret achievements?

Tags: achievements, cookie-clicker

Some achievements in cookie clicker show up only with "???" description and sometimes also as name. What are their names and requirements?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the full list of [achievements](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements):

[image: Normal Achievements]

Here is the table broken down.  ??? are bolded.

```
Row|Column| Achievement                 | Criteria
---+------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------
 1 |   1  | Wake and bake               | Bake 1 cookie
 1 |   2  | Making some dough           | Bake 100 cookies
 1 |   3  | So baked right now          | Bake 1,000 cookies
 1 |   4  | Fledgling bakery            | Bake 10,000 cookies
 1 |   5  | Affluent bakery             | Bake 100,000 cookies
 1 |   6  | World-famous bakery         | Bake 1,000,000 cookies
 1 |   7  | Cosmic bakery               | Bake 10,000,000 cookies
 1 |   8  | Galactic bakery             | Bake 100,000,000 cookies
 2 |   1  | Universal bakery            | Bake 1,000,000,000 cookies
 2 |   2  | Timeless bakery             | Bake 5,000,000,000 cookies
 2 |   3  | Infinite bakery             | Bake 10,000,000,000 cookies
 2 |   4  | Immortal bakery             | Bake 50,000,000,000 cookies
 2 |   5  | You can stop now            | Bake 100,000,000,000 cookies
 2 |   6  | Cookies all the way down    | Bake 500,000,000,000 cookies
 2 |   7  | Overdose                    | Bake 1,000,000,000,000 cookies
 2 |   8  | How?                        | Bake 10,000,000,000,000 cookies
 3 |   1  | Casual baking               | Bake 1 cookie per second.
 3 |   2  | Hardcore baking             | Bake 10 cookies per second.
 3 |   3  | Steady tasty stream         | Bake 100 cookies per second.
 3 |   4  | Cookie monster              | Bake 1,000 cookies per second.
 3 |   5  | Mass producer               | Bake 10,000 cookies per second.
 3 |   6  | Cookie vortex               | Bake 100,000 cookies per second.
 3 |   7  | Cookie pulsar               | Bake 1,000,000 cookies per second.
 3 |   8  | Cookie quasar               | Bake 10,000,000 cookies per second.
 4 |   1  | A world filled with cookies | Bake 100,000,000 cookies per second.
 4 |   2  | Let's never bake again      | Bake 1,000,000,000 cookies per second.
 4 |   3  | Clicktastic                 | Make 1,000 cookies from clicking.
 4 |   4  | Clickathlon                 | Make 100,000 cookies from clicking.
 4 |   5  | Clickolympics               | Make 10,000,000 cookies from clicking.
 4 |   6  | Clickorama                  | Make 1,000,000,000 cookies from clicking.
 4 |   7  | Clickasmic                  | Make 100,000,000,000 cookies from clicking.
 4 |   8  | Click                       | Have 1 cursor.
 5 |   1  | Double-click                | Have 2 cursors.
 5 |   2  | Mouse wheel                 | Have 50 cursors.
 5 |   3  | Of Mice and Men             | Have 100 cursors.
 5 |   4  | The Digital                 | Have 200 cursors.
 5 |   5  | Just wrong                  | Sell a grandma.
 5 |   6  | Grandma's cookies           | Have 1 grandma.
 5 |   7  | Sloppy kisses               | Have 50 grandmas.
 5 |   8  | Retirement home             | Have 100 grandmas.
 6 |   1  | Friend of the ancients      | Have 150 grandmas.
 6 |   2  | Ruler of the ancients       | Have 200 grandmas.
 6 |   3  | Elder                       | Own every grandma type. (Antigrandmas not neccesary)
 6 |   4  | My first farm               | Have 1 farm.
 6 |   5  | Reap what you sow           | Have 50 farms.
 6 |   6  | Farm ill                    | Have 100 farms.
 6 |   7  | Production chain            | Have 1 factory.
 6 |   8  | Industrial revolution       | Have 50 factories.
 7 |   1  | Global warming              | Have 100 factories.
 7 |   2  | You know the drill          | Have 1 mine.
 7 |   3  | Excavation site             | Have 50 mines.
 7 |   4  | Hollow the planet           | Have 100 mines.
 7 |   5  | Expedition                  | Have 1 shipment.
 7 |   6  | Galactic highway            | Have 50 shipments.
 7 |   7  | Far far away                | Have 100 shipments.
 7 |   8  | Transmutation               | Have 1 alchemy lab.
 8 |   1  | Transmogrification          | Have 50 alchemy labs.
 8 |   2  | Gold member                 | Have 100 alchemy labs.
 8 |   3  | A whole new world           | Have 1 portal.
 8 |   4  | Now you're thinking         | Have 50 portals.
 8 |   5  | Dimensional shift           | Have 100 portals.
 8 |   6  | Time warp                   | Have 1 time machine.
 8 |   7  | Alternate timeline          | Have 50 time machines.
 8 |   8  | Rewriting history           | Have 100 time machines.
 9 |   1  | Antibatter                  | Have 1 antimatter condenser.
 9 |   2  | Quirky quarks               | Have 50 antimatter condensers.
 9 |   3  | It does matter!             | Have 100 antimatter condensers.
 9 |   4  | Builder                     | Own 100 buildings.
 9 |   5  | Architect                   | Own 400 buildings.
 9 |   6  | Engineer                    | Own 800 buildings.
 9 |   7  | Enhancer                    | Purchase 20 upgrades.
 9 |   8  | Augmenter                   | Purchase 50 upgrades.
 10|   1  | Upgrader                    | Purchase 100 upgrades.
 10|   2  | One with everything         | Have at least 1 of every building.
 10|   3  | Mathematician               | Have at least 1 antimatter condenser, 2 time machines, 4 portals, 8 alchemy labs and so on (128 farms, grandmas, and cursors)
 10|   4  | Base 10                     | Have at least 10 antimatter condensers, 20 time machines, 30 portals, 40 alchemy labs and so on.
 10|   5  | Centennial                  | Have at least 100 of everything.
 10|   6  | Golden cookie               | Click a golden cookie.
 10|   7  | Lucky cookie                | Click 7 golden cookies.
 10|   8  | A stroke of luck            | Click 27 golden cookies.
 11|   1  | Fortune                     | Click 77 golden cookies.
 11|   2  | Leprechaun                  | Click 777 golden cookies.
 11|   3  | Cookie-dunker               | Dunk the cookie.
 11|   4  | Elder nap                   | Appease the grandmatriarchs at least once.
 11|   5  | Elder slumber               | Appease the grandmatriarchs at least 5 times.
 11|   6  | Elder calm                  | Declare a covenant with the grandmatriarchs.
 11|   7  | Sacrifice                   | Reset your game with 1,000,000 cookies baked.
 11|   8  | Oblivion                    | Reset your game with 1,000,000,000 cookies baked.
 12|   1  | From scratch                | Reset your game with 1,000,000,000,000 cookies baked.
 12|   2  | Nihilism                    | Reset your game with 1,000,000,000,000,000 cookies baked.
 12|   3  | Uncanny clicker             | Click really, really fast.
 12|   4  | Neverclick                  | Make 1 million cookies by only having clicked the big cookie 15 times.(Previously Shadow achievement)
```

Additionally, there are several special (cheating/hard to get) achievements that do not show up until unlocked.  These achievements do not give milk.

[image: Hidden Achievements]

- **Black cat's paw**: Click 7777 golden cookies.
- **Cheated cookies taste awful**: Hack in some cookies.
- **God complex**<sup>3</sup>: Name yourself Orteil.
- **Hardcore**<sup>1</sup>: Get to 1,000,000,000 cookies baked with no upgrades purchased.
- **Speed baking I**<sup>1</sup>: Get to 1,000,000 cookies baked in less than 35 minutes played time.
- **Speed baking II**<sup>1</sup>: Get to 1,000,000 cookies baked in less than 25 minutes played time.
- **Speed baking III**<sup>1</sup>: Get to 1,000,000 cookies baked in less than 15 minutes played time.
- **True Neverclick**: Make your first 1,000,000 cookies without any big-cookie clicks.
- **Just plain lucky**<sup>3</sup>: You have 1 chance in 500,000 every second of earning this achievement.
- **Getting even with the oven**<sup>2</sup>: Defeat the Sentient Furnace in the factory dungeons.
- **Now this is pod-smashing**<sup>2</sup>: Defeat the Ascended Baking Pod in the factory dungeons.
- **Chirped out**<sup>2</sup>: Find and defeat Chirpy   the dysfunctioning alarm bot.
- **Follow the white rabbit**<sup>2</sup>: Find and defeat the elusive sugar bunny.

<sub><sup>1</sup> You cannot use heavenly chip upgrades</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Only available on 1.037 beta</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> These achievement's icons aren't shown</sub>

### **NOTES**

Most achievements are pretty self-explanatory, but these notes should help you with the others.

- **Elder** (Own every type of grandma) does not require *Anti-Grandma*
- **Cookie-dunker** (Dunk the cookie) requires you to re-size the screen.
- **Uncanny Clicker** (Fast clicks) you need [5 clicks in a third of a second or less](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements#cite_note-4)
- "Reset your game with X cookies baked" are cascading (i.e. if you achieve **Nihilism** you also unlock the other 3).
- **True Neverclick** (1 mil cookies, no cookie clicks) can be done with 2 Golden Cookies to get enough for a cursor.  The only clicks that count against this are ones on the big cookie.
- **Cheated cookies taste awful** can be done [a number of ways](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Cheating#Cheated_cookies_taste_awful_achievement).  Those are Spawning a Golden Cookie, Having more cookies than total cookies earned, or simply unlocking the achievement `Game.Win('Cheated cookies taste awful')`.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer (though I only asked for the secret ones :P), I didn't know about the "really" secret ones! I think "Dunk the cookie" requires some explanation though (that you have to resize the screen such that the big cookie swims in milk when you click it)

Comment: @Zommuter I've updated with some notes for the unclear achievements.

Comment: There are multiple new [shadow achievements](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements#Shadow_Achievements) for speed baking.

Comment: @SadlyNot Thank you for the reminder.  I have updated the lists and images.

Comment: There is a new non-shadow secret achievement (right after Neverclick): **Wholesome**, "Unlock 100% of your heavenly chips power."

Comment: I've just unlocked a new shadow achievement **Just Plain Lucky**, "You have **1 chance in 500,000** every second of earning this achievement"

Answer (score 3):

So far I got:

- 16 achievements for the **total amount of baked cookies** (1, 100, 1'000, -> all powers of 10 up to 10<sup>13</sup> = 10'000'000'000'000 except 10; plus 5'000'000'000, 50'000'000'000 and 500'000'000'000)
- 10 achievements for the **maximum CpS so far**, cookie frenzies count here as well (1, 10, ... -> all powers of 10 up to 10<sup>9</sup> = 1'000'000'000)
- **Just wrong** Sell a grandma
- **Elder** Own every grandma type
- **Builder/Architect/Engineer** Own 100/400/800 buildings
- **Enhancer/Augmenter/Upgrader** Purchase 20/50/100
- **One with everything** Have at least 1 of every building
- **Mathematician** Have at least 1 time machine, 2 portals, 4 alchemy labs, 8 shipments etc. (128 max, so you only need 128 cursors, not 256)
- **Base 10** Have at least 10 time machines, 20 portals, 30 alchemy labs, 40 shipments and so on
- **Centennial** Have 100 of each building
- **Golden cookie/Lucky cookie/A stroke of luck/Fortune/Leprechaun** click 1/7/27/77/777 golden cookies
- **Cookie-dunker** resize the screen such that the cookie is in milk and click it
- **Elder nap/slumber** Appease the grandmatriarchs at least once/five times
- **Elder calm** Declare a covenant with the grandmatriarchs
- **Sacrifice/Oblivion/From scratch/Nihilism** (soft-)resetting the game with one million (10<sup>6</sup>) / one billion (or milliard in BE, i.e. 10<sup>9</sup>) / one trillion (10<sup>12</sup>) / one quadrillion (10<sup>15</sup>) cookies baked (since last reset)
- **Uncanny clicker** Click really, really fast

Comment: The 3 ??? ones are: Sell a grandma, 100 upgrades (though I got it at 90something), Have 100 of each building.

Comment: You list off the 4 conditions for soft-resets, but say there are 3 of them? Soft reset achievements count your current cookies (all-time) at time of reset, not total cookies reset ever - I cover that [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130939/how-does-the-prestige-system-work-when-soft-resetting/130941#130941). You're missing the name for 100 of each building (hint: it's Centennial). You could probably list them out instead of grouping them like that. You can always just check the source code in a developer console (Chrome's a good choice) - search for Game.Win for achievements.

Comment: @skovacs1 Thanks, I fixed/added that. I won't list the names of all the total cookies / CpS so far achievements though, that's just too tedious...

Comment: Your call. In my world, it's just copy pasta, but this answer's good enough.

Comment: Who uses ' to separate numbers?

Comment: @Batophobia Switzerland. I actually find it more intuitive than a comma (or the German 1.000,4 which you'd write as 1,000.4), though personally I prefer [SI prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) to such long expressions; and I loathe the ambiguity of "billion" etc. (which means 1e9 in the US but 1e12 in most of Europe)

Comment: Very informative, thanks.  Still looks weird to me though :)

Answer (score 0):

- Cheated Cookies taste awful-Hack in some cookies
- Hardcore-Get to 1 Billion cookies baked with no upgrades purchased
- Speed baking I-Get to 1 million cookies baked in 35 minutes
- Speed baking II-Get to 1 million cookies baked in 25 minutes
- Speed baking III-Get to 1 million cookies baked in 15 minutes
- True never click-Make 1 million cookies with no cookie clicks

Comment: Welcome to the ArQAde! That downvote (not me) was probably a bit too harsh, but please do some formatting in the future - click on `edit` to see how little effort that takes